# images not showing after website deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have img tag in my view as below

```
    <img src="@Url.Action("Images", "MemberImage", new { image = TempData["id"]+".jpg" }) " 
alt=" " style="width: 100px;height:150px" />
```

My controller is

```
public ActionResult Images(string image)
        {
            var root = @"\\server1\PHOTOGRAPHS received\photos";
            var path = Path.Combine(root, image);
            path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
            if (!path.StartsWith(root))
            {
                // Ensure that we are serving file only inside the root folder
                // and block requests outside like "../web.config"
                throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
            }

            return File(path, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

This is working perfectly in my local system but when i deployed to IIS the picture is not displaying.
The server where IIS installed has access to this path
Any other configuration i need to do?

Comment: What status code do you get when you browse to the image, 404, 500 or something else? Do other pages on the site work ok (e.g. a flat HTML page)

Comment: @NikolaiDante the page is loading with other details..the area where image need to be loaded is coming as small rectangle.when i inspect element it showing `src="Client/MemberImage/Images/12345.jpg"` and giving message image cannot be loaded.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to www.yoursite.com/Client/MemberImage/Images/12345.jpg ? Is Client a Virtual Directory on your IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

The server may have permission to the shared directory, but it would be worth checking that the account that the website runs under (the one the app pool is using) has access to the share.

Comment: wesite also run with the same user 'admin'